# Extract dynamic object values in object array

Tags: javascript

I have the object

In below object type value is changed . Based on the type value , have to extract the result from gap.Typevalue

ResultArray is object , i tried to get the CategotyFirst objects values as dynamic

```
var type = ResultArray.type;  // CategotyFirst

var arrayResult = ResultArray.gap.type ; // not getting result

$id: "123"
$name: "test"
type : "CategotyFirst" 
gap :
    CategotyFirst: {
        ...
        ...
    }
    

  var type = ResultArray.type;  // CategotySecond

$id: "123"
$name: "test"
type : "CategotySecond" 
gap:
    CategotySecond: {
        ...
        ...
    }
```

Comment: ResultArray.gap[ResultArray.type]

Comment: your ```ResultArray``` is object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is supposed to be like below.

```
 var type = ResultArray.type //CategoryFirst
 var arrayResult = ResultArray.gap[type] //value of CategoryFirst
```